# How to convert form-data body content with file upload from postman to jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have this post request in POSTMAN that is in form-data in the body that has file upload, wanted to know how to convert this is jmeter.

[image: PostMan Request]

Answer (score 0):

Just record it.

1. Copy `prod logs.txt` file to "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. Start JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)
3. Configure Postman to use JMeter as the Proxy:

   [image]
4. Run your request in Postman
5. JMeter will store the relevant [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

More information: [Recording File Uploads with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/recording-file-uploads-jmeter/)

Comment: hi, I tried with the recording, but since I have to change the proxy in postman when I run the rest call in postman I am getting 'Could not get any response' hence there is not result in the recording. I wasn't able to record running in postman, any other options?